# Codeigniter call stored procedure into transaction

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Why stored procedures never commit in a transaction, when I executed the next function the changes never are reflected:

```
function insertar ($pIdEmpresa) {

  $this->db->trans_begin();

  $query = $this->db->query("CALL bdAltaDetFacturasLabsXSucursalAbonos($pIdEmpresa)");

  if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
  {
      $this->db->trans_rollback();
  }
  else
  {
      $this->db->trans_commit();
  }

  return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
$query = $this->db->query("CALL bdAltaDetFacturasLabsXSucursalAbonos(?)", $pIdEmpresa);
```